# Error when trying to execute an SQL query using OLEDB in C#

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

When I'm trying to execute the query an error occurs:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression [Day]=? AND [Company]=? IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO IsSent2([Day], [Company]) VALUES(?,?).

The code is:

```
try
{
    string commandText = "UPDATE IsSent2 SET [Day]=?, [Company]=? WHERE [Day]=? AND [Company]=? IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO IsSent2([Day], [Company]) VALUES(?,?)";

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(commandText, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "05Jun2017");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", "Test123");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", "05Jun2017");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", "Company");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", "05Jun2017");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", "Company");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
catch (OleDbException oledbex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(oledbex);
}
```

I am out of ideas where the error might come from, do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: That doesn't look like _an_ SQL query.

Comment: are you able to execute your query through SSMS?

Comment: For starters, there are two queries, without separation. I would be highly surprised if that worked. Secondly, are you 100% sure that you shouldn't use named parameters? Have you tried to execute a _single_ query, and maybe with _named_ parameters instead of the `?`?

Comment: I don't know what database you are using so instead of correcting syntax I suggest you split it into two queries and check the rowsaffected in c#

Comment: @Vicky S Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Everything works fine until I add "IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO IsSent2([Day], [Company]) VALUES(?,?)". I am using access database.

Comment: don't think Access supports @@ROWCOUNT so even if you separate statements with semicolon I think it will error

Comment: IIRC `IF` and `@@ROWCOUNT` don't exist in Access SQL.

Comment: So don't add the second part in the same query then. You are executing a query, not a stored procedure. _Maybe_ it could work if you close you first part with an `;` but why don't you just use separate queries?

Comment: Oh crap... Thank you all!

Comment: @oerkelens I tried to everything in 1 query so it is more time efficient but if I can't use @@ROWCOUNT in access, then 2 queries will be.

Comment: I would specify the parameter type.  The oledb is using either the JET driver or the ACE driver.  Both have issues when first column is a DateTime.  The drivers are expecting an integer as the first column.  So the Date Time is probably splitting date into multiple columns.   For example of the date is 1/1/17 the driver may be splitting results into three columns.  So when you get to last column the is more data than parameters.